How to run an event study with many individuals and few observations per individual?
I am trying to run a study on bond issuance, with a specific policy shock that occurred for all units simultaneously. I was planning to use DiD methods, however I'm only observing an individual issuing a bond a few times, if they even issue multiple times. Ideally I'm trying to show that post the treatment event bonds issued by group A (a more treated group) have smaller gross spreads relative to group B (a less treated group). Does anyone know of any papers, resources, or methods that could be of use for this? I've considered aggregating issuances in a region, or matching units issuing in the same time period and showing the gap between A and B shrinking post event. I'm just uncertain of what Econometric method would be most appropriate.
